# cant save multiple rows to associated model

Tags: php, cakephp

I am wanting to get values into my asscociated table and and with my code I get the correct output on $this->request->data. I am saving correctly to the timesheets table but no records are saved to the timesheetLessons table.

The timesheet table has a 1 to many relationship with timesheetLessons.
Looking at the docs I thought I just had to specify the modelname and savAssociated should work but it doesnt.

I have checked the docs and past posts , where past posts refer to another method of simplying avoiding the view. I am sure there is a simple answer as I get the correct data returned.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

**Controller**

```
    class TimeSheetsController extends AppController {

      debug( $this->request->data);
           if ($this->request->is('post') ||$this->request->is('put')) {


              $this->TimeSheet->create();
          if (   !$this->request->data['TimeSheet']['tutor_id'])
          {
              $this->request->data['TimeSheet']['tutor_id']=$tutorId;
          }


            if ($this->TimeSheet->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
```

**View**

```
   <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>tutor id</th>
            <th>date</th>     
         </tr>

      <?php 
              echo $this->Form->create('TimeSheet');
              echo '<tr>';
       // debug($timesheet['TimeSheet']['tutor_id']);
              echo $this->Form->hidden('TimeSheet.tutor_id');
              echo $this->Form->hidden('TimeSheet.id');
              echo   $this->Form->input('TimeSheet.tutor_name', array('label' => 'Tutor name', 'value'=>$tutor_name)); 
              echo   $this->Form->input('TimeSheet.invoice'); 
              echo   $this->Form->input('TimeSheet.note'); 
              echo   $this->Form->input('TimeSheet.abn'); 


          echo '</tr>';
        foreach ($lesson as $key => $item2):
      //  foreach ($lesson as  $item2):   
               echo '<tr>';
               echo   '<td>'.$item2['Lesson']['id'].'</td>'; 
               echo   '<td>'.$item2['Lesson']['tutor_id'].'</td>'; 
               echo   '<td>'.$item2['Lesson']['lesson_date'].'</td>'; 

               echo $this->Form->hidden('TimesheetLessons.'.$key.'.id',
                            array('value'=>$item2['Lesson']['id']));

               echo $this->Form->hidden('TimesheetLessons.'.$key.'.tutor_id',
                            array('value'=>$item2['Lesson']['tutor_id']));

               echo $this->Form->hidden('TimesheetLessons.'.$key.'.lesson_date',
                            array('value'=>$item2['Lesson']['lesson_date']));
          echo '</tr>';
```

**correct output**

```
array(
    'TimeSheet' => array(
        'tutor_name' => 'teacher2',
        'invoice' => '8',
        'note' => '',
        'abn' => '3242',
        'tutor_id' => '16',
        'id' => '1'
    ),
    'TimesheetLessons' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '18',
            'tutor_id' => '16',
            'lesson_date' => '2014-10-06'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '19',
            'tutor_id' => '16',
            'lesson_date' => '2014-10-13'
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

in saving the data, try this. I hope it can help you. :)

```
if($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
    $update = $this->TimeSheet->updateAll(
        array(
            'TimeSheet.tutor_name' => "'" . $this->request->data['ControllerFunctionName']['tutor_name'] . "'",
            'TimeSheet.invoice' => "'" . $this->request->data['ControllerFunctionName']['invoice'] . "'",
            //add some columns here
            ),
        array('TimeSheet.id' => $this->request->data['ControllerFunctionName']['id'])
    );
    if($update){
        foreach ($this->request->data['TimesheetLessons'] as $x):
            $updateTL = $this->TimesheetLessons->updateAll(
                array(
                    'TimesheetLessons.tutor_id' => "'" . $this->request->data['ControllerFunctionName'][$x]['tutor_id'] . "'",
                    'TimesheetLessons.lesson_date' => "'" . $this->request->data['ControllerFunctionName'][$x]['lesson_date'] . "'",
                    //add some columns here
                    ),
                array('TimesheetLessons.id' => $this->request->data['ControllerFunctionName']['id'])
            );
        endforeach;
        //some setFlash message and redirect
    } else{
        //some setFlash message and redirect
    }
}
```

Comment: I have never seen an answer like this before ,are you sure there isnt an easier way? Shouldnt saveassociated work?

Comment: this is not a good approach, I guess. If there are functions provided by the framework, why to do so??

Like wise we have saveAll() or we can go with the one you mentioned above or we can manually use multiple save(). Those serves the purpose but is not a good programming practise.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->TimeSheet->saveAssociated($this->request->data)`. It will serve the purpose.

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer posted.

Comment: This link is definitely helpful but add your explanation why this will work because the link shared may lost in future.

Comment: this doesnt work.I already have this code given in the answer and it doesnt work. Look at my code, i tried this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307640/cakephp-saving-associated-data

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413601/cakephp-saving-associated-model-data

Go through both the links you will know what wrong you might have done. Good Luck!

Comment: I have spent hours on researching this and you post an answer that i already used which didnt work. Can you address your solution please.

Comment: I dont see any code that is different from what I had. What is the solution exactly? It still doesnt save to the associated table TimesheetLessons

Comment: I still get cant this to work as I doing everything the docs say ot appears. Do I need to set the fk id of the associated field manually to the id of the parent model?